# Alternatives to Google Libraries/DotNetOpenAuth for Google OAuth2

Tags: c#, oauth, google-oauth

I'm looking for the easiest way to authenticate against google oAuth 2.0 implementation for the purpose of accessing the google Drive API.  These are the constraints:

- It has to be .NET 2.0 compatible
- Can *not* use the google libraries
- I'll be using a service account to do work on behalf of specific users

I've looked at DotNetOpenAuth, but the version for the .NET 2.0 runtime doesn't seem to support oAuth 2.0 (google has deprecated oAuth v1, which DNOA supports, of course).

Google's documentation is confusing, at best (witholding explitives here).

Comment: Your title was horrible.

Comment: *Why* can it not use the Google libraries? That seems to be the most obvious approach, so you should explain why it's not an option. (The same reason may apply to other solutions.)

Comment: A better title might be Alternatives to Google API/DotNetOpenAuth for Google OAuth2. A good title will help the right people find your question. You already named the two options I know of.

Comment: Thanks, I've adjusted my title.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not sure an explaination why I can't use the libraries matters, just that I can't use them.  It's just one of the constraints I'm working under.

Comment: @user185320: It matters because it affects what other solutions are applicable. It's always worth giving reasons why the obvious normal solution isn't applicable in your case.

Comment: @JonSkeet - that makes sense. 

We'd prefer to use an XML request/response model, JSON (sent from the sever, not client), or some other direct approach rather than a wrapper.

Comment: @user185320: From which server? A Google server, or your own? The choice of request/response formats feels like it's somewhat orthogonal to whether or not you use a wrapper library...

Comment: Our server (JSON/XML) -> google server (JSON/XML) -> Our Server

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but the since you mentioned direct JSON, XML, etc. Google has a UI that simulates and generates requests as well as provides some limited documentation that might get you started on creating such code:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

The following provides some additional info on the login:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

Far from exhaustive but it's a start if that's your angle.